# Netbeans changes DB table type from InnoDB to MyISAM after redeployment.

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, netbeans, innodb, myisam

I set up the database tables to use the InnoDB engine and run my project from netbeans, everything runs fine until i make a change in a file and save it, after redeploying the project again my database tables change from InnoDB to MyISAM and all entries from database tables get deleted. If someone can help it would be greatly appreciated. I am running glassfish server 4.

Comment: Can you please post some sample code or a reproducible test case for us to understand your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Edited the persistence.xml file from configuration files folder and changed the property value: property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop and create tables" to property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none"